# Bounding Euclidean norm by slanted 1-norm

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

For $(x,v),(x',v') \in \mathbb{R}^{2d}$, if we set $$r\left((x,v),(x',v')\right) = \alpha|x-x'| + |x-x' + \gamma^{-1}(v-v')|,$$ where $\alpha,\gamma \in (0,\infty)$ are fixed constants. It is mentioned (without any proof) in this [paper [1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01617), [arXiv pdf link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01617.pdf) that $$|(x,v) - (x',v')|^2 \leq (1+\gamma)^2\max(1,\alpha^{-2})r\left((x,v),(x',v')\right)^2.$$ The advertised inequality can be found in page 26 (equation (5.15)), where the definition of $r$ appears in page 8 (equation (2.9)).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Edit: This inequality is ultimately used to control the new Wasserstein semi-metric $W_\rho(\mu,\nu)$ in terms of the standard $L^2$ Wasserstein distance $W^2(\mu,\nu)$. To be more precise, it is used to obtain (2.23) in Corollary 2.6 from (2.17) in Theorem 2.3.

---

[1]: *Eberle, Andreas; Guillin, Arnaud; Zimmer, Raphael*, [**Couplings and quantitative contraction rates for Langevin dynamics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/18-AOP1299),  [ZBL07114709](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07114709).

Comment: why the downvote...? I feel this is not a easy question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because the question has clear context. I mean, asking for help in a tricky step in a paper is an *excellent* question! The only way I could see that the question could be improved would be if the OP stated *precisely where* in the paper the problem step is - but noone commented to say this, so I don't know what people were after.

Comment: @user1729 I have seen some meta comments/posts claim a good source is reasonable context, but of course not everyone agrees. The paper is not that long, so on a $<1$ minute glance-through I found that the inequality in question is $(5.15)$, pg 26, where $r((x,v),(x'v'))$ is defined in $(2.9)$, pg 8 (on the arXiv ver.)

Comment: @FeiCao I asked in the CURED chat room about how this question could be improved, and the point seems to be that you should try to isolate the precise issue you have with proving the inequality. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58736239#58736239).

Comment: @user1729 Thank you for your comment, I have edited the OP so hopefully this improves the quality of this question.

Comment: I ultimately reopened this question, as I believe that it hits the minimum requirement for this site.  However, there are ways in which the question could be improved.  A more complete reference would help---for example, it seems that the semi-metric is defined on page 9, but I don't have the energy to look for the claimed inequality (citations to the page numbers would help).  It would also be helpful to know the context in which this inequality is used.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  I have edited the OP so hopefully this improves the quality of this question. This inequality is ultimately used to control the new Wasserstein semi-metric $W_\rho(\mu,\nu)$ in terms of the standard $L^2$ Wasserstein distance $W^2(\mu,\nu)$.

Comment: @FeiCao: the one sentence explaining that the inequality helps to control $W_\rho$ in terms of $W^2$ is the sort of thing that would add a lot of "context" to your post. I recommend adding it to the question body.

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks, I have included what you suggested!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG $x'=v'=0, g=\gamma, a =\alpha,$ , and $r(x,v)=a|x|+|x+g^{-1}v|$.

Now
$$|(x,v)|^2=|x|^2+|v|^2,$$
and the first term is easy to bound:
\begin{align} |x|^2 &= a^{-2} a^2|x|^2\\
&\le  a^{-2} (a|x|+|x+g^{-1}v|)^2\\&= \max(1,a^{-2}) r(x,v)^2.
\end{align}For the second:\begin{align}|v|^2 &= g^2 |g^{-1}v|^2 \\
&\le  g^2(|x| +|x+g^{-1}v|)^2 
\\
&\le g^2\Big(\fbox{$(\max(1,a^{-2}))^{1/2}a|x|$} +(\max(1,a^{-2}))^{1/2}|x+g^{-1}v|\Big)^2 
\\
&= g^2\max(1,a^{-2})(a|x|+|x+g^{-1}v|)^2
\\
&= g^2\max(1,a^{-2}) r(x,v)^2.
\end{align}
Adding the two inequalities gives the result (actually, something stronger as $1+g^2\le (1+g)^2$):
$$|(x,v)|^2 \le (1+g^2)\max(1,a^{-2}) r(x,v)^2.$$
In obtaining the boxed term, we used
$$ a^{-2}\le \max(1,a^{-2}) \implies 1\le \max(1,a^{-2})a^2 \implies |x|^2 \le \max(1,a^{-2})a^2|x|^2. $$

Comment: Thank you very much! But there is a bug, the line $|v|^2 = g^2 |g^{-1}v|^2 \le  g^2|x|^2 + g^2|g^{-1}v+x|^2$ is wrong, you are missing a factor of $2$ I believe.

Comment: @FeiCao Yes, that is an issue. I'll give it a think

Comment: @FeiCao I've fixed it, I believe

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my question and post such a beautiful solution!